# SQLAlchemy Table Not Reflected In Database

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm confused about when the tables get changed in the database to match class objects defined in SQLAlchemy's Declarative Model.

For instance, I have a table `commands` with these fields

```
Command.__table__
Table('commands', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<commands>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'), table=<commands>), Column('command_title', String(length=50), table=<commands>), Column('command_desc', String(length=100), table=<commands>), Column('time_added', DateTime(), table=<commands>), Column('time_updated', DateTime(), table=<commands>), Column('favorite', Boolean(), table=<commands>), schema=None)
```

However, when I try to add a new row in my database, SQL will complain. I think this is because I just added the column `favorite` and it has yet to be reflected in the database.

ERROR :

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) table commands has no column named favorite u'INSERT INTO commands (user_id, command_title, command_desc, time_added, time_updated, favorite) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (2, u'HI', None, None, None, 1)
```

Comment: Please describe where and how you added new column? Did you updated database schema to reflect this change?

Comment: I had a file called models.py where I had a class that inherited from Base and had a class variable as "favorite = Column(Boolean())". Is this the schema you are referring to or are you referring to the schema in the actual database which may not reflect the most recent model?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your database could be out of sync with your model.py.

Quick solution would be to alter table statement to your database to add column. We are using similar approach for production code.

I.e. in sqlite:

```
ALTER TABLE commands ADD COLUMN favorite BOOLEAN;
```

or from python with SQLAlchemy engine configured:

```
engine.execute("ALTER TABLE commands ADD COLUMN favorite BOOLEAN")
```

Alternative approach I'm using for another project - I create database schema using sqlalchemy `engine.create_all()` every time model.py is changed. And then load test data - but this is tedious for database that contain production data.

Migrations can be way to go ([Alembic](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic) module for SQLAlchemy do this in database agnostic way). But writing data migration requires some effort and it pays of on relatively big projects.